# Javascript in Chrome: supposed array returns 'true'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In Chrome this code returns "true", in Firefox it returns "0,0":

```
hndl.translate=[pos1[0]-pos0[0],pos1[1]-pos0[1]];
alert(hndl.translate)
```

Both pos1 and pos0 are arrays that have been verified to contain valid numbers. hndl is juist an object. My guess is that it does not matter that much in this context.

Even stranger, changing the second line to:

```
alert([pos1[0]-pos0[0],pos1[1]-pos0[1]])
```

returns "[0,0]", just as I would expect.

What is happening here?

Comment: Use the console for debugging.

Comment: Can you post what pos1 and pos0 are?

Comment: I highly doubt you get `true` as output.

Comment: @Felix, trust me: the alertbox shows 'true'

Comment: @bioball - pos1=[461, 139,0], pos0=[461,139,0].

Comment: @elclanrs I do too, I'm just using the alert to force the program to halt at this point. A bit blunt, i know.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/9KWND/

Comment: @FvEldijk if you want to halt at any point of execution, use `debugger` keyword in your code, or place a breakpoint in source tab. It's much better for debugging, becouse you can actualy see that value and not its .toString() output, like alert does

Comment: @bioball: you are right. The isolated code does not do this. But I cannot imagine anything in the code that influences these straightforward lines.

Comment: Just to show you the problem: follow this link [link]http://traxeditor.com/?mod=Trax&ID=132964127403522330[/link], draw just one straight piece of track and start dragging by one of the dots. Keep a close watch on the console, I put in some debugging dumps.

Comment: ...solved: I failed to notice that hndl is a dom-object. Testing with normal objects did not produce the same results. Changing the property name from 'translate' to 'translation' solved the problem.

Comment: That would have been my other assumption: that hndl is some object with a translate property that is not writeable. But I never heard about such a property so I thought it was a bit of a stretch. Anyways, you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

...solved: I failed to notice that hndl is a dom-object. Testing with normal objects did not produce the same results. Changing the property name from 'translate' to 'translation' solved the problem.